# Existe un comando en git para hacer un commit y una etiqueta al mismo tiempo?

Tags: git, github

Busco un comando en git que me permita hacer un commit y a la vez una etiqueta del commit.

Answer (score 0):

Como tal, las opciones de un *commit* no está la facultad de poder hacer un commit en conjunto con un tag a la vez, lo que sí puede hacer es hacerlo como secuencia. por ejemplo:

```
git commit -m "insert message here" | git tag v1.0
```

Espero sea la respuesta que buscas.

Comment: grandioso justo lo que buscaba, ahora se que se podía hacer de manera secuencial.

Comment: bienvenido a SO! La respuesta es bastante apropiada, pero veo un detalle. Utiliza una tubería (`|`) de forma innecesaria. Sería preferible usar `&&` (dos ampersand, no uno solo) por dos razones. Primero, no hay necesidad de conectar la salida del commit con el tag (cosa que hacen las tuberías) y adicionalmente si el commit **falla**, igualmente se ejecutaría el tag. Con el `&&` no se conectan las entrada/salida de los dos procesos **y** se evitar ejecutar el tag si el commit falla.

Comment: Entiendo. Pero sí el commit falla ¿el tag a qué commit se anclaría?.

Comment: con `&&`? No se ejecuta el tag. Usando `|` como indica esta respuesta donde estamos comentando, se efectuaría sobre la revisión actual ya que no se creó una revisión nueva ya que falló el commit.